Bind sort to parameter , add input sorting option
I would like to know if it is possible to to bind a sort order and sort field to a parameter.
Id like to allow users to select from the option lists which field and what sorting order they would like to sort the visual.
for example, I have a bar chart that show CY and PY value, so the users can sort CY Descending by using the option.
is there any examples or documentations that I can bind sort?
I found this one online, but it shows a lot of warning, I guess it's not allowed to use signal?
online editor

Those are just spec validation warnings as signals are not formally supported in VL but they obviously work when the code is transpiled to Vega.
